# restore root account on ubuntu running in EC2

Tags: ubuntu, root, passwd, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [root locked out of EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/144988/root-locked-out-of-ec2)

How can I restore root account that is running on EC2 Ubuntu platform?

In the /etc/passwd the root username got replaced with something like this - "text with space"
Now I cannot log in using the root password. I was able use a user account to login but this user account does not have any admin privs.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You enable the root account on Ubuntu by first reading the [strong warnings in the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling_the_root_account), and then if you still want to proceed...

```
sudo passwd root
```

If the `/etc/passwd` file is corrupt, you can fix it by running

```
sudo vipw
```

See also this question for information on [enabling root access via ssh](https://serverfault.com/q/216174/126632).

Comment: @Sashi said: _but this user account does not have any admin privs._